# Android drawCircle with different colour border

Tags: android, android-canvas

Is it possible to draw a circle on a canvas in Android with a different colour border using only one `drawCircle` method?

I have noticed the PaintStyle of FILL_AND_STROKE but cant seem to have different colours for both the fill and the border.

I really don't want to have to call two drawCircle methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definition of Paint.Style says:

```
Paint.Style The Style specifies if the primitive being drawn is filled, 
stroked, or both (in the same color).
```

So it seems it can't be done in one go.

If you do this a lot you can create a static helper method that does two calls to draw bordered circle.

Or you could create a custom [android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/Shape.html) object and override its draw(..) method.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks Peter Knego!

if in case any one in need of Shape xml here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#FFFF00" />
    <size
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp" />

    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try making a class and creating the circle with borders by making two one smaller than the other then use the class as your shape instead of the predefined shapes

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a circle with Syle.STROKE a layer over the other circle.

Comment: as the question suggests is it possible with one drawCircle call. your method is what I was trying to get away from